# How to truncate table that my user owns in Oracle without error message

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Thanks for reading this post. I am running into a strange issue in Oracle 10g. I am trying to figure out how to truncate a table without errors being generated.

**What I need to do:**

- truncate a table that my user owns

`truncate table EXAMPLE_USER.EXAMPLE_TABLE;`

**What is happening:** rows within the table are successfully removed, but the following error is generated:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
truncate table EXAMPLE_USER.EXAMPLE_TABLE
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 50
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
       (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
       can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```

**What I have already done:**

- Ensure that EXAMPLE_USER has the "drop any table" privilege
- Make sure that the rows are removed after truncate statement is ran

**Additional Info:**

- I cannot simply drop and re-create the table because the truncation happens as part of a large database upgrade/update script which is out of my control.
- The error is leading me to believe that the truncate statement within Oracle uses some sort of sys package or procedure that my user does not have privilege to access or use, based on the "at line 50" portion of the message. The actual truncate statement itself is a single line script. Does anyone have experience with this issue in Oracle?

Regards,
Dave

Comment: I'd guess that you have a DDL trigger that is throwing an error.

Comment: Do you mean a trigger on that specific table? I have tried created a brand new table, free of any triggers, with the same results. It seems to always be "at line 50".

Comment: @DavidZemina - no, that would be a DML trigger. Justin is referring to [a trigger on a DDL event](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS2063), such as a drop. I'd guess that it is trying to log the drop and can't see the logging table, or is trying to look up something about the table. Maybe ask your DBA about the trigger if you can't see it? (Also you don't need `drop any table` to drop a table in your own schema).

Comment: @AlexPoole - thanks for the clarification. I was able to successfully truncate the table by the following `ALTER SYSTEM SET "_SYSTEM_TRIG_ENABLED"=FALSE;` and then running the truncate script. However, I am fairly certain this parameter was never set to `FALSE` in the past, within our db. I then re-enabled the setting to `TRUE` and I looked at the triggers under the sys user, and only 3 are enabled. I individually disabled these 3 and still receive the error. Do you know how to track down the specific trigger that is causing the issue? They must be triggers I can't see in the sys user.

Comment: `SYS` can see everything, but wouldn't necessarily own the trigger. Look at the `triggering_event` in `dba_triggers`?

Comment: @AlexPoole - I was able to identify the trigger causing the issue (using the `triggering_event` within `dba_triggers` - thanks!) to be under the `MDSYS` user. Trigger is called `SDO_GEOR_TRUNC_TABLE`. It fires `AFTER TRUNCATE ON DATABASE`. I assume that means whenever a table within the entire database instance is truncated. I suppose the issue now is to find out where the "table or view does not exist" is stemming from.

Comment: I had to `GRANT SELECT ON SYS.ALL_TABLES TO MDSYS;` in order to resolve the issue. Now I can freely truncate without this error. Thanks @AlexPoole and @JustinCave for the assistance.